# Mocking Eventemitter in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing

There is need to mock/replace standard Eventemitter of nodejs for unit tests of node modu;e
What is the best way to do it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: why can't you use the EventEmitter? (it pretty minimal)

Comment: "Best" is an extremely subjective term.

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at [deride](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deride)

I use a combination of deride and [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire) to inject in my deride stubs.

There is the ability to force events for testing...

```
var bob = deride.stub([]);
bob.on('message', function() {
    done();
});
bob.emit('message', 'payload');
```

---

> DISCLAIMER: I am one of the authors of deride :)